# Запрет на ввод своего значения в Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

Когда пользователь выбирает элемент из списка в Combobox, он может ввести и свое значение, выглядит это так:

[image: можно ввести что угодно]

Можно ли запретить пользователю вводить что-то свое, чтобы он вибирал только доступные варианты?

Comment: [`ComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2367750/312041) ?

Answer (score 2):

```
ComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
```

Спасибо юзеру tym32167 !